# Android textview different style for bold text

Tags: android, textview

I have a  long string, with multiple bold words inside the string.
The styling of the non bold sentences are done inside the TextView XML part and this is looking fine.

But i want to make the bold words bigger and thicker.
Is this possible to change this with XML?
for example:

```
<string name="long_text">This should be a <b>long</b> text with different <b>styling</b></string>
```

The bold words are supposed to be 1.5 times bigger

Or should i do this in the Java code?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_size.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you have to do this in java because there is no way to as per your requirement,
you can use `TextAppearanceSpan` in java code with `Spannable`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext
i found my answer here thanks! selectingText can help

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting you right than try the following..

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.long_text)));
```

Mark as right if it works for you .